# product thumbnail/ quantity/ price don't displayed on the 'Recently added item(s)' after moving to server

Tags: php, magento, webserver, local, product

After moving my Magento from local to server, the product thumbnail/ quantity/ price don't displayed on the 'Recently added item(s)' part. Can anyone help me? Many thanks!

**On Local**
[image]

**On server**
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you reindex everything